# Dynamic Date Range Data slicing

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to create a weekly report on Jupyter notebook for a data set that is being pulled from SQL database. I need to slice data based on date range from the data set.

Data is being pulled for last 60 days from the current date but I need to pull data (based on data completeness/others) for 30 days in between. To do this I was using the following code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.now().date()
start = today - timedelta(days=10)
end =  start- timedelta(days=30)
Df5= Df5.loc[start : end]
```

The last part of the code, gives the following error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and
>   'datetime.date'

Is this the most efficient way to slice the data? I am new to python and this is the first time working on real world data so any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit Nick

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of your dataframe (using `Df5.head()`) and the datatypes of the columns (using `Df5.dtypes`)?

Comment: So looks like I can't upload an image yet (since I am new). Here's what I have Date Category Count
11/9/2018 Category 1 53502
11/9/2018 Category 2 75217
11/9/2018 Category 3 177188
11/9/2018 Category 4 23725
11/9/2018 Category 5 14901
11/9/2018 Category 6 146195
I did change date from object to datetime but still returns empty dataset

Comment: You don't need to upload an image. Just type `Df5.head()` in your Python terminal and copy+paste the output into the question. Do the same with `Df5.dtypes`.

Comment: So I was able to solve this issue by making these two changes                  `import datetime 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index("date", inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)                                                                                            
 today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
start = (today - datetime.timedelta(days=10)) # .isoformat()
end = start-datetime.timedelta(days=30)  df_last30 = df.loc[end:start]`

Answer (score 0):

Your `.loc` statement will only work if the index of `Df5` is a `DatetimeIndex`. From the error, it appears your index is an `int` type.

If you have a datetime column in `Df5`, then you need to set that as the index:
`Df5.set_index("name_of_date_column", inplace=True)` and then use your `.loc` statement.

Or, you can change the `.loc` statement to use the column with the date:

`Df5.loc[Df5["name_of_date_column"].between(left=start, right=end)]`

Either way, you need to be comparing `start` and `end` to datetime data types.

Comment: Thanks Wilk for responding. So I get an invalid syntax error pointing to the colon in the second part of the code when I use the first approach `Df5.set_index("Date", inplace=True)  Df5=Df5.loc(start : end)` . The second approach doesn't give any errors but return an empty dataset with just the column names.

Comment: When you use `loc`, you have to use brackets:
`Df5=Df5.loc[start : end]`